# which UUID's hashcode equals to Integer.MIN_VALUE

Tags: java, algorithm

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String uuid = null;
    while ((uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "")).hashCode() != Integer.MIN_VALUE){};
    System.out.println("i got one! " + uuid);
}
```

i cannot find out the result.
even i do not know whether the result exists.
help me.

Comment: I read your question and title for 3 times but I still don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: What result? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one exists.  In fact, roughly one random UUID in `2^32` will have a `hashcode` that is equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  If you run your test for long enough, you will find one.

Comment: I have tested about 1,000,000,000 uuids .Sadly i didn't find one.

Comment: 2^32 is roughly 4 billion, so I'm not surprised you didn't get a hit in the first 1 billion tries.  Out of curiosity, is there a point of this exercise ... apart from increasing your power bill?  :-)

Comment: Maybe the result exists in roughly statistics, just maybe. But i cannot prove it in mathematics. :(

Comment: Yes you can (could).  The algorithm used to create the `hashcode` of a string it is specified, and is simple enough that you reverse engineer a string of hex digits with any given 32 bit hash.  The existence of such a string is a mathematical proof-by-existence.